# How to add gems manually in Logstash 1.5.0

Tags: rubygems, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have some gem files in my local folder. How can I install that into my Logstash 1.5.0. I have already installed it in logstash 1.4.2 but I dont know how to install it in 1.5.0. I couldn't find any input,output and filter folder in newer version of logstash 1.5.0 to check my avaialble gems.

It would be a great help for me if any one help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file myplugin.gem under C:\Downloads then you can issue following command from logstash installation directory:

```
bin\plugin install C:\Downloads\myplugin.gem
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Ya you can also use bin\plugin install --local C:\Downloads\myplugin.gem. While installing you can also ignore the dependence to avoid that we can use bin\plugin install --local C:\Downloads\myplugin.gem --ignore-dependencies